# No validation does not work when adding multiple

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am trying to do the validation of ui-select with the option multiple option.
But no angular validation works. Even creating a custom validation. That always returns invalid.

Only remove the (multiple) option that all validations work (required and customized)

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="Model.Test" close-on-select="false"
           search-enabled="true" required custom-validation>
    <ui-select-match allow-clear="true">{{$item.Name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in Items | filter:$select.search">
        <div ng-bind-html="item.Name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

```
app.directive('customValidation', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.customValidation = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEboLq

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your codepen doesn't match the code in the question. You didn't mention that you are using `jcs-autovalidate.js`.

Answer (score 0):

> That always returns invalid.

It works better if the validator returns `true`:

```
app.directive('customValidation', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.customValidation = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶;̶
                return true;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: It was only an example to show even with always returning invalid.  It does not appear as invalid.  It's not the final code.  It is sample code to demonstrate what the problem is.

Comment: @RudáCunha It definitely shows invalid when `false` in my tests. What version of AngularJS are you using? What version of `angular-sanitize.js`? What version of `ui-select/dist/select.js`?

Comment: In the example it only valid the second select, the first always returns as valid. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEboLq